# ASP.NET MVC - delete a user in default account system?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, controller

How does one 'properly' delete a user from the system in ASP.NET MVC?

I have a Customers controller which ties into the default Account controller well for the most part but when it comes to deleting them, deleting from the Customers table isn't enough as the user name is now effectively "reserved".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution:

System.Web.Security.Membership.DeleteUser(username);